# Set PENDING lock to EF core SqlLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, transactionscope, ef-core-2.1

I'm developing ASP .Net Core Web-api application with EF Core and SqlLite. If there are a lot of select queries, update queries works very slow. When number of queries grow I get 'database is locked' error. 
I think the problem is "Writer starvation", so I want to set PENDING lock to my updates when DBContext is saving data to DB.

How can I set PENDING lock using EF core? is there any other solution?

UPD:

1. database locked sometimes occurs even if there is not a lot of queries
2. packages:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Abp.AspNetCore.OData" Version="3.8.2" /> 
   <PackageReference Include="Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="3.7.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Abp.AspNetCore" Version="3.8.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="jquery.datatables" Version="1.10.15" />
   <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="2.0.7" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.0.1" />        
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.8.391" />    
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions" Version="1.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="NLog.MailKit" Version="3.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.7.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="4.3.1" />    
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
   <PackageReference Include="Abp.Dapper" Version="3.8.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Abp.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.8.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.4" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.4" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Entity Framework provide any way to set Pending lock for updates but you can get this behavior using `Database.Begin` API to begin, commit and rollback transactions.

You can start transaction when updating any thing and commit transaction after completing your updates during this interval no one will able to update any data in Database.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //Did your work here

            //During this time it will help as a pending lock for other updates
           transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO: Handle failure
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully it will cover your problem.

**Updated**

Please note that only those queries which execute using another instance of `BloggingContext()` will be set in pending lock this behavior wouldn't be apply on instance of `BloggingContext()` which was used to start transaction.

Comment: is it works with sqlLite? i add logging to context and it seems that EF do not support sqlLite transactions

Comment: @Timur Lemeshko It should work. I don't see this limitation for SQLite. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations

Comment: If it doesn't support then `NotSupportedException` should be thrown.

Comment: i have no any exceptions. There is "commiting transaction" at logs,but  really  no START TRANSACTION and COMMIT at logs and looks like transactions really didn't work, but i'm not shure

Comment: The BEGIN and COMMIT statements are sent by the ADO.NET provider and aren't logged by EF Core.